# SQL INNER JOIN exception

Tags: sql, exception, syntax-error, derby

I'm new to SQL queries and I'm trying to join two tables

I need to get all data of the followers of userID = 2

here's the error i get : `Syntax error: Encountered "INNER" at line 1, column 39.`

and here's the SQL query I ran :

```
SELECT * FROM FOLLOWER 
WHERE userID = "2" 
INNER JOIN USERS ON FOLLOWER.Follower_userID = USERS.userID 
ORDER BY USERS.follower_count ASC
```

**The tables in my DB are :**

FOLLOWER

---

- ID
- userID
- Follower_userID

USERS

---

- userID
- username
- password
- Nickname

P.S
I'm using Apache Derby.

Thank you so much guys.

Comment: Just a side note: Do not use double quotation mark (`"`) for string literals `"2"` in your query. By turning `[QUOTED_IDENTIFIER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx)` it has different meaning (identifier quoter :)). Additionally you do not have to pass integer values as string literals: it could lead to unexpected results or unnecessary implicit datatype conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

position of where clause was incorrect

structure of SELECT query is

```
SELECT fields
FROM tables
WHERE conditions
ORDER BY fields
```

so you query should be

```
SELECT * 
FROM FOLLOWER INNER JOIN USERS ON FOLLOWER.Follower_userID = USERS.userID
WHERE userID="2" 
ORDER BY USERS.follower_count ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM FOLLOWER Fl
WHERE userID="2" 
INNER JOIN USERS Us ON Us.userID = Fl.Follower_userID
ORDER BY USERS.follower_count ASC
```

Let me know if it's works

Answer (score 0):

First use join and then where.

```
SELECT * FROM FOLLOWER INNER JOIN USERS ON FOLLOWER.Follower_userID = USERS.userID WHERE userID=2  ORDER BY USERS.follower_count ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Inner Join` syntax

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 AS T1
    INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2
    ON T1.Table1ColName = T2.Table2ColName
ORDER BY T1.Table1ColName
```

Refer this link for [Inner Join](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx)

Change your query like

```
SELECT * FROM FOLLOWER
INNER JOIN USERS 
           ON FOLLOWER.Follower_userID = USERS.userID
WHERE userID="2"  
ORDER BY USERS.follower_count ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 

`SELECT * FROM FOLLOWER 
INNER JOIN USERS 
         ON FOLLOWER.Follower_userID = USERS.userID
WHERE FOLLOWER.userID="2" 
 ORDER BY USERS.follower_count ASC`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The rules of where with join is first made all join and then give where condition which filter more data..

so your where condition just put after inner join as above all suggested.

```
select * 
from yourtable
join yourothertable
where condition if you want
```

http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/850159-performance-conditions-where-clause-vs-conditions-inner-join